# Install or not Git on Mac OS

Tags: xcode, macos, git

I have a Mac OS X Version: 10.8.2 with Xcode 4.5.2.

I'm going to use git and I'm not sure if I have to install it or not.

Searching on my computer, I've found it here: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git`

If it's needed I going to install this [distribution](http://git-scm.com/download/mac). **Is this the right one?**

**Is it necessary to install Git or can I use the one who comes with Xcode?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to install a newer version of `git` if the one that comes with Xcode doesn't support a feature you want, or, of course, fixes a bug.

You need to install the Xcode Command Line package, in order access things like git from the standard path (`/usr/bin`).  You can do that within Xcode itself.

If you need to install a newer version of git, I would recommend the [Macports](http://macports.org) version.

I rarely use the command line version of git on my Mac, preferring to do complex source control operations using the excellent, and free, [Atlassian SourceTree](http://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview) app.

Comment: And, I will need git-svn, also. Where can I download it?

Comment: @VansFannel If you are using the Macports version of git, then it looks like to have to install `git-core` with the `svn` variant; i.e. `$ sudo port install git-core +svn`.

Comment: @VansFannel Do you have Macports installed?  If not, see this: http://www.macports.org/install.php

Comment: Why the Macports version?  I don't think it offers anything above and beyond the distribution pointed to by the OP.  IIRC, git-svn comes with the Mac distribution above.  No need for Macports.

Comment: @jszakmeister If you can confirm that, then let the OP know; as I mentioned, there is only a need to install the Macports version if you want a feature that's unavailable in the Xcode version.

Comment: @trojanfoe Just because it's not in Xcode doesn't mean you need to install the Macports version.  The [Mac version on git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) is full-featured and has git-svn (I did confirm this). Macports is nice, but I think it's a bit much to get something that is already packaged nicely for the Mac.  And it's certainly a higher bar to cross for newbies.

Comment: @jszakmeister I agree; if it's just `git` you want, then using a pre-built binary is quicker and easier.  However once you have installed Macports, `git` won't be the only thing you will install...

Answer (score 0):

You can, however, do note, it's an older version than the distribution. Personally, I use [homebrew](https://brew.sh)'s version of git.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Xcode and have no plan to uninstall Xcode 4.5.2 (or newer), then git is already available to you. The only thing is the git version bundled inside Xcode may not be the latest. Another thing is to use git (bundled inside Xcode) from the console or Terminal.app, then you'll need to prefix your command with

> xcrun

See the man page for more detail.

On the other hand, if you want to use git without requiring Xcode, then download the git source, and build using the makefile will allow you to customize git to your needs.